# Using licensed image in a blog

Tags: images, licenses

I would like to use some images which are not mine in my blog (which is in development stage).

Since I don't own the image I searched for images on Google which are labeled for **reuse with modification**. Also I searched on Flickr by filtering on license **Commercial use and mods allowed**.

My first question is is my filtering correct if I want to use some one's else image on my blog.

Secondly after I have found the image with proper license, as I understand I need to provide reference to the image. How do I do that? Should I just paste the link below the image I picked from Flickr or Google? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 3):

> My first question is is my filtering correct if I want to use some one's else image on my blog.

**Yes** (although you might be able to use less strict rules depending on your specific needs, e.g. if you want to use an image unedited or if your blog is non-commercial).

> Secondly after I have found the image with proper license, as I understand I need to provide reference to the image. How do I do that? Should I just paste the link below the image I picked from Flickr or Google? Or is there some other way?

**It depends**. You should examine the license that the image is provided under.

For example, I did a search for "old west" and turned up these images:

[Outhouse](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Outhouse_in_an_old_west_scene.jpg) which says:

> Credit me as author using the following credit line clearly and legibly next to the image: "Betty Wills, Wikimedia Commons, License CC-BY-SA 4.0".

and

[Wagon](https://pixabay.com/en/wild-west-wagon-wooden-wheels-53886/) which says:

> Public Domain. Free for commercial use. No attribution required

Answer (score 0):

Each and every image that was created own by a copyright if they provide their image/art to modify then it was okay if not you have to search who is the creator of that image.

### To find the original creator?

We can find an image easily on the internet but finding an original creator of that image was a challenging task. There were about a lot of images over the internet and you can take and modify it for your own purpose for blogging purposes at all you need to get a copyright authority to use those for that you have to contact that creator of that particular image. 
All of them are ready to give their image to publish them on your website if you ask politely but for that, you need to give some credentials for their work it's up to you.

### Another way to get a lot of free images for Blogs?

One more way is you can use those free non-copyrighted image for your blogs.
some of the sites are

1. google image
2. Flickr
3. ccsearch
4. Wikimedia commons

In the above websites (there are a lot of websites I mentioned only 4) you can download the images by using the options **reuse with modification** and some other **non-commercial reuse with modification**. Those are all the methods you can get images for your blogs.

I Hope that I'll help your queries. If not then feel free to ask in comments..!!